Creating an array that requires all values from literal union without creating a tuple
My end goal is to be able to replace a value for a given type with my new union literal. And when that new union literal changes i want the typescript compiler to show that we're missing a value, similar to a Record, but without replacing the actual keys, of the object, that lives inside an array:
My thought process goes something along the lines of:

Create an a Tuple from my Union Type
Spread out my tuple, and replace the value of the the Type with the Union literal.

So this works and is what I wanted, It's throwing errors if i add a new value to the Union type, which essentially is what i needed. Then i stumbled upon this: Why this is a BAD idea and i decided to stop right there. Is there some other way to achieve the effect without resorting to creating a tuple and then spreading it?
// This is the Literal union i want to be responsible for throwing errors if we add more types
type TaskKind = 'Foo' | 'Bar' | 'Baz';

type Option = {
  value: string | number | boolean | null | undefined;
  label: string;
};

type ReplaceValue<T, K extends keyof T, U> = Omit<T, K> & Record<K, U>;

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (
  U extends unknown ? (arg: U) => 0 : never
) extends (arg: infer I) => 0
  ? I
  : never;

type LastInUnion<U> = UnionToIntersection<
  U extends unknown ? (x: U) => 0 : never
> extends (x: infer L) => 0
  ? L
  : never;

type UnionToTuple<U, Last = LastInUnion<U>> = [U] extends [never]
  ? []
  : [...UnionToTuple<Exclude<U, Last>>, Last];

type SpreadTuple<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer First, ...infer Last]
  ? Last extends any[]
    ? [ReplaceValue<Option, 'value', First>, ...SpreadTuple<Last>]
    : [ReplaceValue<Option, 'value', First>]
  : [];

const options: SpreadTuple<UnionToTuple<TaskKind>> = [
  { label: 'Foo', value: 'Foo' },
  {
    label: 'Bar',
    value: 'Bar',
  },
  {
    label: 'Baz',
    value: 'Baz',
  },
];


TS doesn't have a notion of an exhaustive array. Is there a reason you don't use an object instead, like {Foo: fooOptions, Bar: barOptions, Baz: bazOptions}? Objects are much easier to track for exhaustiveness than arrays.
